# Dr. Brennan's Academic Position?

Tags: character, bones

Dr. Temperance "Bones" Brennan is the foremost Forensic Anthropologist in the world. As part of that, she works as the chief Forensic Anthropologist at the Jeffersonian Institute's Medico-Legal Lab, working closely with the FBI. She has a team of interns which were initially chosen from her students. Throughout the series, there are multiple mentions of her students or status as professor, but nothing was ever mentioned on her actual academic status.

**What is Dr. Brennan's position, with which university? What department? Does she have tenure? And how often does she teach?** The closest I've seen was her Lecture in Season 1 Episode 5 "*A Boy in the Bush*" where Booth shows up mid-lecture.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think she (currently, as of the TV show) has an academic position. Universities sometimes allow guest specialists to lecture for a class, and as a foremost specialist she is probably in demand for that. The students may have been before she worked at the Jeffersonian Institute when she had been a professor somewhere.